# Authentification whith phone number with firebase in ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I just want to create an ionic mobile app (using firebase) with a phone number authentification, but I don't know how I should proceed. Does someone could help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do these steps:

```
Activate Phone Number Authentication in your Firebase Console.
Set up reCAPTCHA verifier.
Send the SMS
Sign the user in.
```

*.html*

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Phone Number</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <button ion-button id="sign-in-button" (click)="signIn(phoneNumber)">
    Sign In
  </button>

</ion-content>
```

*.ts*

```
signIn(phoneNumber: number){
  const appVerifier = this.recaptchaVerifier;
  const phoneNumberString = "+" + phoneNumber;
  firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString, appVerifier)
    .then( confirmationResult => {
      // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
      // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
      let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Enter the Confirmation code',
      inputs: [{ name: 'confirmationCode', placeholder: 'Confirmation Code' }],
      buttons: [
        { text: 'Cancel',
          handler: data => { console.log('Cancel clicked'); }
        },
        { text: 'Send',
          handler: data => {
            confirmationResult.confirm(data.confirmationCode)
            .then(function (result) {
              // User signed in successfully.
              console.log(result.user);
              // ...
            }).catch(function (error) {
              // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
              // ...
            });
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    prompt.present();
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error("SMS not sent", error);
  });

}
```

Here is the [**Great article about it**](https://javebratt.com/firebase-phone-authentication/).I extracted above code from this article.

[**Offical doc**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth)

Comment: thank ypu @Sampath. i will try it

Comment: OK sure.No problem :)

Comment: it's giving me that error (Error: ./node_modules/firebase/utils/promise.js) Iwiil try to fix it but if you have any idea...

Comment: it's ok now. thank you :)

Comment: i just realize that is not working on mobile

Comment: Any console errors? You can do device debug.

Comment: no there is not console error is just not working on mobile device

Comment: How's your progress here? Working now?

Comment: no. I finally opted for authentication with mail address. thanks for your help :)